# Update tooltip for specific point in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Code:

```
var series = projectsChart.series;
for (var i in series) {
    for (var j in allProdArray) {
        var x = parseInt(j);
        if (x % 4 === 0) {
            if (series[i].name === allProdArray[x]) {
                series[i].addPoint(parseInt(allProdArray[x+3]));
                series[i].update({
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<small>{series.name}</small><table>',
                        pointFormat: '<tr><td>KPI Metric:</td><td><b>' + allProdArray[x+2] + '</b></td></tr>' +
                                     '<tr><td>Desc:</td><td>' + allProdArray[x+1] + '</td></tr><tr><td>Actual:</td><td><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
                        footerFormat: '</table>'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding points dynamically from an array in my highcharts. I am also adding the labels on the x-axis dynamically after the chart has been initally created and therefore cannot put this tooltip on creation as majority of the fields are null (undefined).

What I want to do is to find a way to **ONLY** update the tooltip of the current point. I want to do this because the values (`allProdArray[x+2]` and `allProdArray[x+1]` are different for each point.

The code that I have at the moment updates the tooltip for the whole series. This causes all data to be overwritten and every tooltip on every point to be the same.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT (more information):**

Each item in `allProdArray` has a different description (labelled `Desc:`) and metric field (labelled `KPI Metric:`) (at positions `[x+1]` and `[x+2]`). As you can see I am looping through this array to add the points individually to the graph. What I want to do is to loop through this array to give each point a different description and metric in the custom toopltip I am creating.

The position of the point value, description and metric should all be within the same value of x. For example, if `x=1` then the value of the point would be `x + 3 = 4`, the metric will be `x + 2 = 3` and description will be `x + 1 = 2`. This is why I was attempting to create a custom tooltip for each point as the values in each tooltip for each point are different.

Again, any help appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a way to specify the tool tip formatting on the point level. What to do depends on how different you want things to be for each point. Often if statements, or external arrays that are referenced are the way to go. You may need to be more specific about what you need to get a good answer.

Comment: @jlbriggs I have updated my question to give more information of the output I desire

Comment: @WillAshworth Tooltip is not created for all points, but it is created dynamically when hovering over points, so using a tooltip's [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) or [pointFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormatter) will allow you to control what is displayed.

Comment: @KacperMadej this is not seeming to work either as all points are getting the same description and metric. Could you potentially get up a jsFiddle? I was thinking about adding the metric and description to the xAxis categories but just hiding them. So I could reference them the way highcharts intended but would not be visible. Is this a sensible approach or not?

Comment: @WillAshworth You could use arrays - http://jsfiddle.net/wxm4qvm0/, or add more data per point - http://jsfiddle.net/wxm4qvm0/1/

Comment: @WillAshworth - yes, exactly what kacper said. You didn't use the set up from my solution in your example.

Comment: @WillAshworth also, to answer your other question: this set up, with a different axis for each bar, serves literally no purpose whatsoever. The bars are meaningless in every way.  The best solution to numbers this varied is to simply present the numbers themselves as text. Good use of spacing, font sizes, and layout will make a very big difference in how effective such a display is.

Comment: @KacperMadej that solution worked, thank you!! However, I changed `this.x` to `this.series.data.indexOf(this.point)` instead to get the index of the point

Comment: @jlbriggs also, thank you for your advice on displaying the chart. It's much simpler and user friendly. Will give it strong consideration